# Text: subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, string, text

Can one check the following code for me, please? I'm  getting repeatedly the error `Error in txt_splitted[[i]] : subscript out of bounds`.

```
library(sringi)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3), 
          text=c("This is text mining exercise text",
                 "Text analysis is bit confusing analyssi",
                 "Hint on this text analysis?")) 
data2 <- data.frame(mult1 = c("text","analysis","bit confusing"),
          mult2 = c("A; B; C","A; D", "A; B; C; D"))

txt <- subf <- frq<- txt_splitted<-list()
pattern <- str_c(data2$mult1, collapse = "|")

for(i in 1:length(data1$id)){ 
  txt[[i]] <- unlist(str_extract_all(data1$text[i], pattern))
  subf[[i]] <- rep(data2$mult2[i], length(txt[[i]]))
  txt_splitted[[i]] <- str_split(subf[[i]], ";") %>% unlist()
  frq[[i]] <- table(txt_splitted[[i]])
}
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but try ```dev.off()```. Sometimes when I get an error that fixes it. Also, your code worked fine for me

Comment: Hi Gadaa, I cannot reproduce your error, so I'm voting to close your question as not reproducible. Try restarting your R session and see if it works.